# Android local notification does not fire after system reboot

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-notifications

I implemented some notifications that fire on specific date and time. My code works if phone is not rebooted after app installation, but if I reboot the phone the notifiction does not fire. I tried many methods proposed by other developers, but nothing changed. Is it possible to restart notification service automatically on system reboot?

> BootService.java

```
package com.example.is2_app.utility;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.JobIntentService;

import java.util.Calendar;

import static java.util.Calendar.APRIL;

public class BootService extends JobIntentService {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        intent = new Intent(this, ReminderBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);


        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()>System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

> ReminderBroadcast.java

```
package com.example.is2_app.utility;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.is2_app.MainActivity;
import com.example.is2_app.R;

public class ReminderBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    void showNotification(Context context) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "your_name";// The id of the channel.
        CharSequence name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        context.startService(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_candida)
                    .setLights(Color.RED, 300, 300)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        } else {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_candida)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        }
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.spazzatura));
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.spazzatura_residuo)));
        mBuilder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.spazzatura_residuo));
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.is2_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".global.Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_candida"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_candida_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <service
            android:name=".utility.BootService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".utility.ReminderBroadcast"
            android:permission = "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I read that it is not possibile to do that nowadays (maybe due to powersaving); so I decided to migrate fo Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: OK thanks.  I think I am going to try and set up something to reschedule all outstanding notifications after the device reboots.